# SwiftUI WidgetKit calling getTimeline multiple times in a row

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

this is my code , sometimes it calls 3  times, sometimes 5, if I use a network call using async with a Task and do , it calls like 20 times till memory drains and crash , this is running the extension on the real device:

```
func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
    
    print("CALLING getTimeline")
  
    let currentDate = Date()
    let updateDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 5, to: currentDate)!
    

            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(),configuration: configuration, items: DummyData.data)
            
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(updateDate))
     
            print("Calling Completion Timeline Discounts ")
            
  
          completion(timeline)
            
           
}
```

OUT PUT

```
Current Date:2023-10-22 23:05:49 +0000 update Date is: 2023-10-23 04:05:49 +0000
Current Date:2023-10-22 23:05:52 +0000 update Date is: 2023-10-23 04:05:52 +0000
Current Date:2023-10-22 23:05:53 +0000 update Date is: 2023-10-23 04:05:53 +0000
Current Date:2023-10-22 23:05:54 +0000 update Date is: 2023-10-23 04:05:54 +0000
```

---

```
CALLING getTimeline
Calling Completion Timeline Discounts 
CALLING getTimeline
Calling Completion Timeline Discounts 
CALLING getTimeline

Calling Completion Timeline Discounts 
CALLING getTimeline
Calling Completion Timeline Discounts
```

Comment: How many times are you calling reload timeline?

Comment: Hey!! Im not calling reload timeline anywhere. Not in the app or extension, the widget is using policy .after to update

Comment: That simple code is calling 3-5 times getTimeline, in my real code where im using await and have task and do , it calls the api constantly till memory runs out or my api blocks the calls with too many requests

Comment: I am having similar issue. Are you on Xcode 15.0.1